# luma-theme .phtml file override in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, module, custom, phtml, theme-luma

i want to override this file **`magento_dir/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/collapsible.phtml`**

And do not want to make custom theme like `app\design\frontend\Magento_Theme\templates\html\collapsible.phtml`

Can we override `collapsible.phtml` in our `custom_module`? 
guide me i will be appreciate to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by overriding the template file in your custom module.

```
app/code/YourVendorName/YourModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml
```

Note : please replace you xml file name with `customer_account_index.xml` and use referenceBlock name according your point of view `sidebar.main.account_nav` or `customer_account_navigation_block`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>        
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation_block">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourVendorName_YourModuleName::collapsible.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

I hope this can work for you.

Comment: i will try it please :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually you can do this.
try this code in your xml of your module

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation_block">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::html/collapsible.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This should work.

Comment: okay i will try it